# Why is my PHP not inserting into database?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have made a simple login to the main webpage. If the user login is successful the username, nickname, and date are supposed to be inserted into the database "userdata" why is this not the case? I don't get any errors, but my database does not update and remains empty.

php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
session_start();

if($_POST['submit']) {
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password, nickname FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND activated = '1' LIMIT 1";
    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root_root"); 
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

    if ($query) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $userId = $row[0];
        $dbUsername = $row[1];
        $dbPassword = $row[2];
        $userLabel = $row[3];
    }


    if ($username == $dbUsername && $password == $dbPassword) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $userId;
        $_SESSION['nickname'] = $userLabel;
        $date = date('m/d/y | H:i:s');

        if ($dbPassword == "password") {
            header('Location: firstlogin.php');
        }

        else
        mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO userdata (username, name, timein) VALUES ('$username', '$userLabel', '$date')");
        header('Location: main.php');
        } 
    else {
        $error = "Error: Invalid username or password.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: just a quick heads up here, `strip_tags` is not a safe escaping function, i'd go for `mysqli_real_scape_string`

Comment: At first glance, the `else` for your INSERT-block should be in brackets (so that it calls both the query and the `header`), and there should be an `exit;` after the `header();` calls. To troubleshoot if a query is failing, put it inside an `if`-statement, like how you did with `if ($query) {`

Comment: Also, might want to use prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root_root");  works?!

Comment: @LucaGiardina They are probably removed for sake of security. :)

Comment: You're simply assuming success on the insert query. Bad idea. **NEVER** assume success when dealing with external resources, especially databases. Even if your SQL is 100% syntactically correct, there's a near infinite number of OTHER reasons your query could fail over (e.g. missing foreign key).

Comment: Thanks for all the criticism guys (seriously I mean that) very helpful! Learning as I'm going

Comment: Dale: Not familiar with this. Returns Call to undefined function mysqli_real_scape_string()

Comment: Okay so I have found my error. Possible fix? "Error: INSERT INTO userdata (username, name, timein) VALUES ('user', 'Test', '11/13/15 | 13:47:16') Field 'timeout' doesn't have a default value"

Comment: Is this your actual code: `$connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root_root");`? because I suspect that's the first problem if it is...

Comment: No. This is for security reasons...